# Json server crash upon reload

Tags: javascript, rxjs, json-server

I am using json-server as a mock API for my rxjs app. I am having problems when sending multiple PUT requests. When I send 2 or more PUT requests the server crashes and the terminal displays the following :

```
PUT /terms/1 200 22.881 ms - 58
PUT /terms/2 200 6.347 ms - 58
bands-db.json has changed, reloading...

Loading bands-db.json
bands-db.json has changed, reloading...
Done

Resources
http://localhost:3000/bands
http://localhost:3000/terms

Home
http://localhost:3000

bands-db.json has changed, reloading...

Loading bands-db.json
bands-db.json has changed, reloading...
Done

Resources
http://localhost:3000/bands
http://localhost:3000/terms

Home
http://localhost:3000

Cannot bind to the port 3000. Please specify another port number either 
through --port argument
or through the json-server.json configuration file
```

I can start the server back up with "json-server --watch bands-db.json" and the PUT requests have modified the data in the way that was intended, I do not get this issue when sending one PUT request

```
data.slice(0,duration).forEach(term => 
    {
      term.bandId = bands[0].id;            
      const $request = ajax
      ({
        url : `http://localhost:3000/terms/${term.id}`,
        method : "PUT",
        headers: 
        {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body : JSON.stringify(term)
      });
    $request.subscribe();
```

This is the request I am sending to the server, for each term in the array modify the coresponding term in the database with a PUT request.

Any ideas what might be causing the issue?